# Transforming old data to "match" updated data

Tags: r, data-transformation

I have a couple of large data sets, one from an older machine and the other from a newer better version. I want to find a value that I could apply to the old data to basically have the new data's values. What is the best way to find this value in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you are hoping that it is a simple linear transformation. First, I would do a "pickup sticks" plot between the two machines. Essentially, just a line for each animal between the measurements from both machines to get an idea of the direction of the effect you should expect. The plot is usually messy but you can usually see a trend if there is one that will help to validate what you find in your statistical model. If there is a solid trend that doesn't tend to deviate more as the measured values increase or decrease (some subjects always will but in general) then you probably have a linear transformation on your hands.

If that is the case, I would recommend a linear model (the call in R is lm() for linear model). You should just have one predictor variable, "Machine" and the estimate (i.e. *b*) that you get will be the linear slope of one machine to the other depending on how your Machine variable is coded. Make sure you model does a good job of predicting, your R squared should be quite high (~.80 or higher; 1 means perfect prediction of every data point by your model). If it does a good job, then your error is low and your transformation should be pretty accurate. Check your residuals (i.e. errors) as well. These should have a relatively normal (Gaussian) distribution if you have a linear relationship between the 2 machines.

However, you also want to link the data of one subject's sample to the other sample from the same subject. Now you technically have a repeated measures analysis. Machine is your repeated measure. A Repeated Measures ANOVA could do this pretty easily, but if you have missing data for subjects on one machine and not the other, or you have some variability that makes you think "this looks pretty linear, but there are definitely a concerning chunk that deviate from that" you will want a method which can account for these issues. A Linear Multilevel Model (aka LMER, or LMM) is the way to go. It is just like an LM with a few tweaks. You still get an estimate just like in an LM that is interpreted the same way but you also can specify a random (as opposed to a fixed/main effect). The syntax for this is below:

```
library(lme4)

model <- lmer(Y ~ Machine + (1|SubjectID), data=yourdata)
summary(model)
```

Back to the estimate. The estimate for Machine is the slope of the "transformation" line in this case between OLD and NEW. You should be able to multiply OLD by the estimate to get a value pretty close to NEW. The intercept estimate will not matter. If you need some help with the syntax let me know.

Comment: The data is measurements taken from semen collections such as volatility and size. The samples were split between the two machines for each animal so it is as close to just differences in the machines as we can biologically get. The goal of this is to find a general formula that we can use to make old data, not necessarily this data, more accurate.

Comment: @CashCab1221 Thanks that really helps! I have edited the answer above to help. If you could post the pickup sticks plot I mentioned, it may help more.

Comment: Thank you, I'm already pretty proficient in R and had basically already done this but didn't know if there was a different better way.

Comment: @CashCab1221 There may be. If you have missing data for some subjects on one machine or the other, some decent variability in that pickup sticks plot, or want to specify that one individual subjects samples should be more like one another than they are like other individuals' samples, you may instead want to use a linear mixed effects model from the lme4 library. It generalizes better out of the original sample than LM. You just need to specify the random effect of "subject" (the intercept linking the subjects' samples together). This would be the most accurate way I know. Edited above to suit